# regex case insensitive and with/without whitespace

Tags: php, regex, highlight, highlighting

Not being that knowledgable in regex patterns and after reading all wikis and references I found I'm having problems altering a pattern for word detection and higlighting.

I found a function on another stackoverflow answer that did everything it was needed but now I found out it misses out on a few things

The function is:

```
function ParserGlossario($texto, $termos) {

    $padrao = '\1<a href="#" class="termo">\2</a>\3';

    if (empty($termos)) {
        return $texto;
    }

    if (is_array($termos)) {
        $substituir = array();
        $com = array();

        foreach ($termos as $key => $value) {
            $key = $value;
            $value = $padrao;
          //  $key = '([\s])(' . $key . ')([\s\.\,\!\?\<])';
            $key = '([\s])(' . $key . ')([\s\.\,\!\?\<])';
            $substituir[] = '|' . $key . '|ix';
            $com[] = empty($value) ? $padrao : $value;
        }

        return preg_replace($substituir, $com, $texto);

    } else {

        $termos = '([\s])(' . $termos . ')([\s])';

        return preg_replace('|'.$termos.'|i', $padrao, $texto);

    }
}
```

Some words are not being highlighted (the ones marked with red arrows):

[image: Words missing out]

And I don't know if it helps, but here is the array of "terms" that is used to search the text:

[image: Words being searched]

**EDIT.** The string being searched is just plain text:

> Abaxial Xxxxx acaule Acaule xxxxxx xxx; xxxxx xxx Abaxial esporos.
>   abaxial

**EDIT.** Added PHP code fiddle

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/079ad24318f554d9f2ba

Any help? I really don't know much about regexes...

Comment: I'm guessing that's an html string? The first Abaxial probably doesn't match coz it's at the start of the string and has no leading space. Show the actual input string (`$texto)`, not just your search terms.

Comment: There's a really straightforward site that gives you some great examples and that you can copy and paste your test text into and try RegEx out on here: (http://www.regexr.com)  you can also download "Expresso 2.0" which is a regex suite that has a decent amount of pre loaded regular expressions.

Comment: @MarcB: Sorry about not posting the string. My fault. It's just just plai next coming from a mysql select.

Comment: @MikeHorstmann: Thanks for the tip, gonna check that out now.

Comment: well, just for kicks, try `\s?($key)([....])?` - make the two sentinels optional. if you start getting the missing stuff highlighted, then you know it's a problem with the pattern, and not the input text.

Comment: @MarcB: I'm trying at regexer and it doens't mark the words with first chat uppercase, also, I'm getting this "preg_replace(): Compilation failed: POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset ..."

Comment: A screenshot of the array being used isn't very useful. We can't execute the provided code because there are missing parts. Please provide a reproducible code sample. Also separate topic but I prefer regex101 over regexr.

Comment: @chris85: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/079ad24318f554d9f2ba

Comment: So something like https://eval.in/481726?

Comment: @chris85: Almost! The middle "Acaule" word is not getting it's hyperlink

Comment: Maybe https://eval.in/481732 although this makes the leading whitespace optional..

Comment: @chris85: That seems to work great.... care to submit it as an answer?

Comment: I think this can be cleaned up a bit. I don't have time right now to post if there isn't an answer that works for you in a bit I'll post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$key = '(^|\b)(' . $key . ')\b';
```

insetad of

```
$key = '([\s])(' . $key . ')([\s\.\,\!\?\<])';
```

should help. Your matches still will be in the second group but there will be no third and I think the first should not be touched, so I believe this

```
$padrao = '\1<a href="#" class="termo">\2</a>\3';
```

is better to be as

```
$padrao = '<a href="#" class="termo">$2</a>';
```

and forgot (sorry):
change

```
$substituir[] = '|' . $key . '|ix';
```

to

```
$substituir[] = '#' . $key . '#ix';
```

And also I would use a string

```
$com = empty($value) ? $padrao : $value;
```

instead of array, it's not needed in this case.

Comment: And by the way what's the point of $com[] = empty($value) ? $padrao : $value;     $value is never empty, since earlier you assigned it a string from $padrao

Comment: I don't really know what was intended with $com[] but you're right, it's better as a string. Your answer worked great and it dealt with plural words very nicely. Just one extra question ... why change $substituir[] = '|' . $key . '|ix'; by $substituir[] = '#' . $key . '#ix'; ? Didn't understand that bid

Comment: metacharacter `|` had to be used inside the expression so the delimiters were to be changed to something different, I picked `#`, you can pick something different if doesn't look cute )))

Comment: I've tried the pattern without first group and it worked well (can't recall what was the way of my tries yesterday). So you might want to reduce the expression to just `$key = '\b(' . $key . ')\b';` or `$key = '\b(' . $key . '[s]?)\b'` for plurals. Eliminating the first group can save some memory and increase speed. In this case also `$2` is to be replaced with `$1` in `'<a href="#" class="termo">$2</a>'`

Comment: `(^|\b)` is the same as `\b` here.

Answer (score 1):

Let us look together on value of `$key` for example for array element `acaule`.

```
([\s])(acaule)([\s\.\,\!\?\<])
```

1. There are 3 marking groups defined by 3 pairs of `(`...`)`.
2. The first marking group matches any whitespace character. If there is no whitespace character like for `Abaxial` at beginning of the string, the word is ignored.

   Putting `\s` into a character class, i.e. within `[`...`]` is not really needed here as `\s` is itself a character class. `([\s])` and `(\s)` are equal.
3. The second marking group matches just the word from array.
4. The third marking group matches

   - either any whitespace character,
   - or a period,
   - or a comma,
   - or an exclamation mark,
   - or a question mark, i.e. the standard punctuation marks,
   - or a left angle bracket (from an HTML or XML tag).

   A semicolon or colon is not matched and other non word characters are also ignored for a positive match.

   If there is none of those characters like for `abaxial` at end of the string, the search is negative.

   By the way: `([\s.,!?<])` is equal `([\s\.\,\!\?\<])` as only `\` and `]` (always) and `-` (depending on position)  must be escaped with a backslash within a character class definition to be interpreted as literal character. Well, `[` should be also escaped with a backslash within `[`...`]` for easier reading.

So it is clear why `Abaxial` at beginning of string and `abaxial` at end of the string are not matched.

But why is `Acaule` not matched?

Well, there is left to this word `acaule` with a space left and a space right as required for a positive match. So the space right of `acaule` was already taken for this positive match. Therefore for `Acaule` there is no whitespace character anymore left to this word.

There is `\b` which means word boundary not matching any character which might be used together with `\W*?` instead of `([\s])` and instead of `([\s\.\,\!\?\<])` to avoid matching substrings within a word.

Possible would be something like

```
$key = '(\W*?)(\b' . $key . '\b)(\W*?)';
```

`\W*?` means any **non** word character 0 or more times non-greedy.

`\W?` means any **non** word character 0 or 1 times and could be also used in first and third capturing group if that is better for the replace.

But what is the right search string depends on what you want as result of the replace.

I don't have a PHP interpreter installed at all and therefore can't try it out what your PHP code does on replace and therefore what you would like to see after replace done on provided example string.

Comment: First let me thank you the detailed explanation. That was something I wanted rather of just giving me a solution. I find regexes truly confusing, and this kind of answer helps a lot! About the solutions: The first $key you give me just doesn't work at all while the second underline the single terms leaing the plural not underline. Take the word "esporos" for example, in the search terms array both words "esporo" and "esporos" are present. That regex underlines the portion "esporo" not underlining the full work "esporos"

Comment: Okay, initial first suggestion removed and remaining suggestion modified to make sure second marking group matches always only entire word from array and never a substring in a longer word like the singular word within plural word.